# How to override model field validation in django rest framework ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-validation

I have the following model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    mobileNumber = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    authKey = models.CharField(max_length=300,null=False,blank=False)
    creationDateTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    lastUpdateDateTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Serializer:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('mobileNumber','authKey')
```

If userprofile model already has a mobilenumber XX44 and if I try to serialize using UserProfileSerializer with json  {'mobileNumber': XX44, 'authKey': u'ggsdsagldaslhdkjashdjkashdjkahsdkjah'} I'm getting the following error:

```
{'mobileNumber': [u'User profile with this MobileNumber already exists.']}
```

because model validations are being run for the serializer field.

How can I stop execution of model field validation for mobileNumber. I have tried validate and validate_mobileNumber methods in serializer but they still are executing the model validations.

Comment: The data you are trying to serialize {'mobileNumber':XX44.....} Is it some random data or data of UserProfile model? Because if it is random unvalidated data then you should not use model serializer to serialize it, just use a normal serializer.

Comment: Try removing 'primary_key=True' from the UserProfile Model.

Answer (score 2):

remove unique constraint on mobile number of table,so django serializer will validate according to that .

or 
alternatively,

```
   serializer=UserProfileSerializer(data=request.DATA,partial=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you won't save the serializer data. So, you can set `mobileNumber` as a `read_only` field on `UserProfileSerializer`.

Check serializer fields documentation for more info: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments

Answer (score 0):

By overriding the model field within the serializer, and specifying `required=False, allow_blank=True, allow_null=True`:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
   some_model_field_which_is_required = models.ForeignKey(...)
   some_other_required_field = models.CharField(...)

class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    some_model_field_which_is_required = SomeNestedSerializer(
        many=True, required=False, allow_blank=True
    )
    some_other_required_field = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)

   def validate(self, *args, **kwargs):
       print('should get here')

   def validate_some_other_required_field(self, *args, **kwargs):
       print('should also get here')

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
```